# How can one align spinners right to left?

Tags: android, textview, spinner, right-to-left, gravity

Can anyone tell me what do I do wrong? :( 
I have 2 Spinners and two TextViews that I want to align right.
I have set everything to right but still everything is left aligned.

Here is how it looks like:

[image]

But I want it too look like this:

[image]

And here is my XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:layout_gravity="right"
android:gravity="right">
    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radios"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:onClick="test"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingRight="10dp" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rbtn_sell"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:button="@null"
            android:drawablePadding="3dp"
            android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
            android:text="@string/label_sell_unicode"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rbtn_rent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:button="@null"
            android:drawablePadding="3dp"
            android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
            android:text="@string/label_rent_unicode"
            android:textSize="12sp" 
            android:paddingLeft="40dp"/>
    </RadioGroup>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_from"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/label_from" 
        />
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:drawable/btn_dropdown"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_to"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/label_to" 
        />
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:drawable/btn_dropdown"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />



</LinearLayout>
```

Update: My XML after making the changes  ElDuderino suggested. After this change the two TextView and the two Spinners are gone. They are nowhere on the screen.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="2">
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radios"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:onClick="test"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingRight="10dp" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rbtn_sell"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:button="@null"
        android:drawablePadding="3dp"
        android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
        android:text="@string/label_sell_unicode"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rbtn_rent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:button="@null"
        android:drawablePadding="3dp"
        android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
        android:text="@string/label_rent_unicode"
        android:textSize="12sp" 
        android:paddingLeft="40dp"/>
</RadioGroup>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_from"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="From" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:drawable/btn_dropdown"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_to"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="To" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:drawable/btn_dropdown"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: If you are targeting 4.2 and above, http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/03/native-rtl-support-in-android-42.html

Answer (score 0):

You made a mistake while adding the drawable on the radiobutton..Try this and lemme know

android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/btn_radio"

Comment: My RadioButtons are fine. But I don't seem to manage the Spinners. Like the picture.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is this :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical" 
 android:layout_gravity="right"
 **android:gravity="right">**
```

You set the top layout to align everything to the right side, so your inner layout, which is set to `wrap_content` doesn't take all the space available and so gets aligned right. So either remove the `android:gravity` from the outer layout, OR set your inner layouts `layout_width` to `match_parent`.

Update, as it didn't work : Replace your inner linear layout with this : (I had to change string resources, but you'll figure out)...

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_from"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="From" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:drawable/btn_dropdown"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_to"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="To" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:drawable/btn_dropdown"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I made these change: Spinners and TextViews and the LinearLayout that contains them: I made them "match_parent". Everything is gone except for the first TextView. Nothing else out of those 4 Views (2 TextViews and 2 Spinners) are nowhere in my screen.

Comment: I replaced my inner layout that contained the TextViews and Spinners with the code you provided. Now nothing is on the screen. All four objects are gone.

Comment: I updated my answer and put the new XML in my answer so that you can see my file maybe you can point what mistake have I made to make the objects disappear.

Comment: You forgot the outer layout in your code. You structure should be like : <LinearLayout> <RadioGroup> </RadioGroup> <LinearLayout> <LinearLayout> </LinearLayout> <LinearLayout> </LinearLayout> </LinearLayout> </LinearLayout>

Comment: There is actually one outer layout, but it wasn't shown here because of tabbing. I fixed the edited part.

Comment: Ok, but you replaced the settings of the outer layout with the settings of the inner layout, just change it back, so that your outer layout says : <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"  ... that will make your layout appear and stretch over the whole width. Now if you want to have that triangle on the other side of the spinner, you will have to create your own background image and set it to the spinner...

Comment: You can find the dropdown file in sdk\platforms\android-XY\data\res\drawable, this will tell you how create a selector yourself.

Comment: I replaced the outer one with what you said and I got the views back on the screen now. (still left to right though). Thanks a lot for your concern. I highly appreciate it. I suppose I have no choice but to make a custom spinner. Thanks again man.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
   android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textView_from"
   android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textView_to"
```

this may help you

Comment: Won't help, it's no RelativeLayout.

Comment: It says Invalid param for LinearLayout. And the link has no link.